# Solving imaginary equation $z^3 = 5i + 5$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I need help solving the equation : $z^3 = 5i + 5$. I'm basically just starting to learn imaginary numbers and how to solve them. 
Straight forward solution is a pain ( was trying to figure out with step-by-step solution from wolframalpha ). After that I was reading wikipedia about them and came across with the De Moivre's formula that states $z^n = |z|^n (\cos(n\phi) + i\sin(n\phi))$ but I have no clue how to use it with this example.

I would greatly appreciate some help on this. Maybe it is possible to do it another way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: OK, the angle is 45° and the magnitude √50 So DeMoivre says that you need to cut the angle by factor 3 and take the cube root of the magnitude. Then repeat the angles by 120° (Do you know why?) Then using CIS you get your three answers. Try it

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_law is it this? If yes, then no. I haven't seen and haven't heard of it. It don't see connection in first sight.

Comment: No, it is not that law. I guess they call it perhaps DeMoivre's Theorem. Hold on here...

Comment: I mean this one http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula

Comment: Here is a worked out example of this law on youtube http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SecLZxQ9lBo

Comment: Well, thanks for the link. 
It's like i have $|z| = \sqrt(50)$ and $\phi = 45$. It's true. I know about repeating with some angle to get another solutions, but what i don't understand is why we cut the angle by 3(i assume it comes from this z^3), cause to this time i was solving only easy equations like $z^4 + z^3 + z^2 = 1$ and the starting point was always on horizontal line. Thanks for any answer and help :)

Comment: Without going into trigonometric proofs, here is something to think about. The angle belonging to 1+i is 45°, right? Now when you multiply this angle by itself, you end up with 2i. Let's see. 2i is on the vertical axis, which makes 90°. 45+45 is 90. So conversely, if you take a squareroot of a complex number (I got to be carefull here with my phrase) you do the opposite: taking half of that angle

Comment: 'Imaginary equation' - first time I have ever heard that... sounds cool, I think I will say that from now on! :)

Comment: Thank you a lot. So it ends up my starting angle is $\frac{\pi}{12}$ and starting magnitude is $50^{1/6}$ right? And my next solutions have same magnitude but angles : pi/12 + 3pi/4 and pi/12 + 3pi/2. Am i right? Or am i just making it as complicated as it possibly could be?

Comment: Enjoy that @zerosofthezeta :-) I'm not speaking english everyday, so i just have to come up with some weird expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$z^3=5(1+i)$$

$$=5\sqrt{2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}})$$

$$=5\sqrt{2}(\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})+i\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}))$$

Do you now see some thing worthy???

Comment: Yes
I end up with $z = 50^{1/6} * cis(\frac{1}{3} * \frac{\pi}{4})$ am i right? 
Im just missing how to take 3 answers from that. I'm pretty close to fully understand the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: forget about taking three answers... just focus on what does $z = 50^{1/6} * cis(\frac{1}{3} * \frac{\pi}{4})$ mean and then you can join $w$ and $w^2$ to $z$ to get remaining 2 roots where $w$ is a cube root of unity...

Comment: you accepted it after two months? any specific reason? :P

Comment: Looked on unaccepted questions on my list and just picked your answer, which helped me.

Comment: @Chris : fine fine :)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can write $$5+5i=\sqrt{50}\operatorname{cis}\frac\pi4,$$ so putting $$\zeta=\sqrt[6]{50} \operatorname{cis} \frac\pi{12},$$ we have $$z^3=\zeta^3\\z^3-\zeta^3=0\\(z-\zeta)(z^2+\zeta z+\zeta^2)=0,$$ and so the solutions are $z=\zeta$, and the solutions to the quadratic equation $z^2+\zeta z+\zeta^2=0.$ As yet another alternative, put $\omega= \operatorname{cis} \frac{2\pi}3,$ so that $1,\omega,\omega^2$ are the complex cube roots of $1$, and so $\zeta,\zeta\omega,\zeta\omega^2$ are the solutions to the equation  $z^3=\zeta^3.$

Regardless you should find solutions $$z=\sqrt[6]{50} \operatorname{cis}\left(\frac\pi{12}+\frac{2\pi k}3\right),$$ for $k=0,1,2.$

Comment: Should the last equation have $\dfrac{\pi}{12}$?

Comment: @TheChaz2.0: Oops! Fixed. My thanks!

Comment: I just missed 12/100 on an exam for that very thing. (Obviously, none of my 6 sixth roots were correct. DAMN!)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that doesn't use any trig.  Assume that $z=a+bi$ with real values for $a$ and $b$.  Expanding $(a+bi)^3$ and separating real and imaginary parts leads to the pair of equations

$$a^3-3ab^2=5$$
and
$$3a^2b-b^3=5$$

This implies $a^3-3ab^2=3a^2b-b^3$, which implies

$$(a+b)(a^2-4ab+b^2)=0$$

All *three* solutions for $z$ have to come from this.  I'll do the easy one, corresponding to $a+b=0$.  Plugging this back into either of the pair of equations gives $-2a^3=5$, or $a=-\sqrt[3]{5/2}$ and $b=-a=\sqrt[3]{5/2}$.  So one solution is

$$z=-\sqrt[3]{5\over2}+i\sqrt[3]{5\over2}$$

To get the other two solutions, it's probably best to multiply this one by ${1\over2}\pm i{\sqrt3\over2}$ (i.e., the complex cube roots of unity).